# Elasticsearch min price of a month

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to receive the lowest prices for the next and previous 15 days from my chosen date in my products index.

How can I get this prices in ES? What kind of query should I write?

My mapping:

```
  {
     "product-data": {
        "mappings": {
           "mine-apple": {
              "properties": {               
                 "date": {
                    "type": "date"
                 },
                 "productName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                       "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "productDescription": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                       "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                       }
                    }
                 },               
                 "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                       "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                       }
                    }
                 },                                             
                 "price": {
                    "type": "long"
                 },               
                 "query": {
                    "properties": {
                       "match_all": {
                          "type": "object"
                       }
                    }
                 }               
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I thought about the aggregation. But it also gives the minimum price of the total result. But I need the minimum price every day. I could not find better idea. How can I do I dont know

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: I found the solution. It can be done by the aggregations. Thanks C-Otto

Comment: Please consider sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Of course, I added now

Comment: Please post that as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Ok C-Otto :) I added

Answer (score 0):

> The solution I found: I added date-histogram to my query.In this way, grouping my query with date-histogram. At the latest I get minimum prices with minimum aggregation.

```
  {
       "query": {
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "range": {
                      "date": {
                         "gte": "2017-05-11",
                         "lte": "2017-05-14"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "size": 0,
       "aggs": {
          "sales_per_month": {
             "date_histogram": {
                "format": "YYYY-MM-dd",            
                "field": "date",
                "interval": "day"
             },
             "aggs": {
                "sales": {
                   "min": {
                      "field": "price"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```